# Problem facing while installing TrueCrypt

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

I downloaded the .tar.gz of TrueCrypt and extracted it. As per instructions, on clicking on the file 'truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x64' we should get a window that asks us to run the setup. But when I open the file in gedit instead of giving out a window.

Help me how to install TrueCrypt.

Following instructions from this site : [link](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/11/encrypt-folders-partitions-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelotpart-i/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the file executable and then run it.

```
sudo chmod +x truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x64
sudo ./truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x64
```

Before running the above commands, you have to cded into the directory where `truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x64` file is located.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the file and go to properties => permissions select "allow executing file as a program"

now double click the file i should run if still not then

open your home folder and go to edit => preferences => behaviour and there under 'Executable text files' select " ask each time "